# Web Audio API: gap between playback when using context.currentTime

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Environment:
Windows 10 and MacOS High Seirra
Chrome and Safari

Use case:
We want to play N number of audio files one at a time. Looping a given audio file on itself with seamlessly until the user toggles another track via UI interaction. Currently we are using a linear fade between the tracks. Because the user can change at what point the track will loop we need to be able to detect the a track position via loop markets and transition between the tracks on the fly. We schedule a fade out of the current gain node and fade in a new gain node of the same track immediately once we hit the end of the loop.

Expected Result:
Using a 110hz cosine signal audio file we loop infinity fading between playback of the sources. Given a perfectly aligned transition between two cosine wave forms of the same frequency we would expect a no amplitude change over the course of the transition between tracks. The two linear ramps of the same duration and starting time should cancel each other out perfectly in this scenario.

Observed Result:
Even though we set the start time of the second source to be the same as the beginning of the fade out of the first, we end up with random amplitude drops in our playback. Occasionally playback will align and we will see the expected result of a aligned waveform.

What could be causing this behavior? Is context.currentTime unreliable to schedule events based on?

This Code is a bastardized version but replicates the issue:

```
function Crossfade() {
  console.log('crossfade function');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/cosine_110hz.wav', true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {

      console.log("track received.");
      let trackStart = context.currentTime + .1;
      let fadeDuration = .25;
      let fadeOutStart = trackStart;
      var gainNode2 = context.createGain();
      var source2 = context.createBufferSource();

      source2.buffer = buffer;
      source2.connect(gainNode2);
      gainNode2.connect(context.destination);

      gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, trackStart);
      gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, trackStart + fadeDuration);
      source.stop(trackStart + fadeDuration);

      gainNode2.gain.setValueAtTime(0, trackStart);
      gainNode2.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, trackStart + fadeDuration);
      source2.start(trackStart, 0);

      gainNode = gainNode2;
      source = source2;
      setTimeout(Crossfade, 1000);
    })
  }
  request.send();
}
```

[Actual waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYEPV.png)

[Expected waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoV4C.png)

https://github.com/JeffreyLangston/WebAudioApiTest

Answer (score 0):

You could implement equal-power crossfade with the [`.setValueCurveAtTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/setValueCurveAtTime) method instead of the `.linearRampToValueAtTime()`. You could use these methods below to create needed curve and adjust it as needed:

```
const curve = new Float32Array(64);

function makeEqualPowerCurveIn(startVolume, endVolume) {
    var range = endVolume - startVolume;
    curve[0] = startVolume;
    for (var i = 1; i < curve.length; i++)
        curve[i] = startVolume + range * Math.cos((1 - i / (curve.length-1)) * 0.5*Math.PI);
    return curve;
}

function makeEqualPowerCurveOut(startVolume, endVolume) {
    var range = startVolume - endVolume;
    for (var i = 0; i < curve.length; i++)
        curve[i] = endVolume + range * Math.cos(i / (curve.length-1) * 0.5*Math.PI);
    curve[curve.length - 1] = endVolume;
    return curve;
}
```